# Custom New button on Opportunity Tab page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, custom-button

I want to add custom NEW button on opportunity tab. I know this can be done by overriding NEW button by custom visualforce page https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AVm8IAG

But If I do this all users will be forced to use either the standard page or the custom page. Cutsom button can be added on either Detail page and list Page.

I would like to have a another New button on opportunity tab that will open my custom page? How can this be done? How can I add my Custom new button on opportunity tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **List Button** to display it on the List view. You can easily create this under Opportunity>Buttons> New Button or Link > in type choose List button.

Comment: how to add this custom button on opportunity tab near New standerd button. List button will be displayed on list view only.